# BizTalk Adapter Registry Wizard not showing Receive Adapter

Tags: adapter, biztalk, webdav, wizard, biztalk-2013

I have written a WebDav Send and Receive Adapter for Biztalk. I can Register the TransmitAdapter but its not showing me the Implemented ReceiveAdapter in the Adapter Registry Wizard.

[image]

This is The Implementation of the WebDavSendTransmitAdapter

[image]

Does somebody know what the Conditions for the RecdeiveAdapter are to show up in the Adapter Registry Wizard?
By the way, for what are the Aliases in the first picture?

Comment: Did you check the "Adapter can receive messages" option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was i had to set the ReceiveAdapter class to public to be visible to the Adapter Wizard.